# Php application moved to another server Windows 2012 with IIS 7, but not working

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012

I have been asked to move a PHP application to another environment. I set up PHP installation, and moved 2 PHP applications and. got that working.

But one application I moved is not working... it just renders a blank screen.

When I say Localhost/ApplicationName, it lists the application folders and PHP files in it. When I click on it, the browser goes blank.

Can somebody point out a step-by step trouble shooting ways to test this?

Comment: a blank screen is the default way to show a 500 internal server error, you need to check the error logs to see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of ways a php file can return a blank page
first make sure the file did work on the previous environment, if it didn't then it's a different issue entirely

do the following in order of what you suspect to be most probable:

- you can go into the php.ini file, and set the error variables to the development defaults, then check if it returns any usable errors
  ^this is what I use all the time for fatal issues, always set it back to it's original afterwards though
  or check the errorlogs, as JimL suggested
- if it worked on the previous env then you need to find out what the differences are between both environments.
  things like, php.ini setting, IIS vs apache or whatever http server, linux vs windows
- check if any of the php pages return anything at all (for example, in firefox, rightclick+inspect element, then use the network tab)
  if it's a 500 error, the file probably has an error (and the server is configured to return 500 on an error)
- if the file isn't too large, you can go through the file and use common programming sense to see if you can easily spot the error (stuff like links to nonexisting files, etc, shouldn't be too hard even without php experience)
  when it links to files, also check if the notation is correct for the windows IIS

feel free to give more information in your OP, or in a comment, if you find out any information, and I'll do my best to help
disclaimer, I have no specific IIS knowledge, I work with apache (both windows and linux)